# How do I get the exit code from my subscript in main script - bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do I get the exit code from my subscript in main script. In my script below when the subscript fails it exits from the main script as well.

```
#!/bin/bash
function reportError() {
    if [ $1 -ne 0 ]; then
        echo $2
        exit $1
    fi
 }

 #executing the subscript

 /data/utility/testFolder.sh
 #calling the function if there is any error then function would update the 
 #audit table
 reportError $? "job is failed, please check the log for details"
```

Subscript code -

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d "/data/myfolder/testfolder" ]
then
  echo "ERROR: Directory does not exists"
  exit 1   
else
    echo "INFO: Directory exists"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: Huh? Nothing in here is changing your current working directory at all.

Comment: BTW, you've got a whole bunch of quoting bugs. Consider fixing everything identified by http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: ...back to trying to identify a problem, though -- please build a [mcve]: The shortest possible code someone else can run without modification or external dependencies to see your problem themselves.

Comment: I have updated the question ,description and code to give more clarity what I need.... regret for the original post which was not clear...

Comment: I could not load an example in shellcheck.net

Comment: There is no subshell here, and no, with the exact script you gave here, the child exiting *does not* cause the parent to immediately exit as well. Which is to say -- this doesn't actually reproduce your stated problem.

Comment: (and re: "could not load an example" -- could you describe in more detail?)

Comment: It'd be helpful use a `#!/bin/bash -x` shebang on both scripts -- that way they'll log each command they run to stderr. If the child *really* terminates with `exit 1` and the parent *really* fails to proceed, that chain of events will be visible in said log.

Comment: Never mind, it just worked. When I clicked "Load an example" the example appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and everything is fine except you made a mistake in the subscript condition.

```
#!/bin/bash
function reportError() {
    if [ $1 -ne 0 ]; then
        echo $2
        exit $1
    fi
 }

 #executing the subscript

 /data/utility/testFolder.sh
 #calling the function if there is any error then function would update the 
 #audit table
 reportError $? "job is failed, please check the log for details"
```

Child script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d "/data/myfolder/testfolder" ] # add "!". More details: man test
then
    echo "ERROR: Directory does not exists"
    exit 1   
else
    echo "INFO: Directory exists"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: "Subscript" isn't a very well-defined term, and it's close to something that would be misleading: "subshell" implies a fork without an exec (thus, a copy of the original shell with all local variables intact), but we *are* having an `exec()` call. It's safer just to call it the "child script" or "child process".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks! I just tried to express the answer in the author's terminology.